# Very strange MediaElement behavior

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Problem 1:

When I play a video and the video ends, 
I play it again in the MediaEnded eventhandler.
The problem is, it only starts playing again when I touch the screen and scroll (audio does play again without scrolling).

Problem 2:

When the video is playing and I scroll, 
as soon as the video starts to go out of screen, 
its starts to stretch and misform.

The XAML is very simple:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="1500" Background="White">
            <MediaElement Source="https://vines.s3.amazonaws.com/v/videos/AC5539AF-9251-4363-A641-E7F01C4E6239-141-0000012CB4E3656E_1.0.mp4?versionId=GzoAU2AQAlSzFs_9XM5u.FF90IScP45j" Width="456" HorizontalAlignment="Left" AutoPlay="True" Stretch="None" MediaEnded="MediaElement_MediaEnded_1"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

NOTE: both problems only occur on a real device, not in the emulator. How can I solve this very, very strange problem?

Answer (score 2):

Hows about,

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

    <!--Basic Windowsphone Way-->
    <StackPanel>
        <MediaElement x:Name="PlayElement" Source="https://vines.s3.amazonaws.com/v/videos/AC5539AF-9251-4363-A641-E7F01C4E6239-141-0000012CB4E3656E_1.0.mp4?versionId=GzoAU2AQAlSzFs_9XM5u.FF90IScP45j" AutoPlay="True" Stretch="UniformToFill" MediaEnded="MediaElement_MediaEnded_1" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And

```
    private void MediaElement_MediaEnded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlayElement.Play();
    }
```